# Search Google results by Header Response

Tags: search, cookies, http-headers, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I want to be able to search google for sites with certain response codes, or cookies that they set. Like Im able to use site:, inurl, etc I was wondering if there is any way to search sites for response cookie like. cookie:cookiename

Is there any search engine that does this?

Comment: You've packed several questions into one, so you need to be clear. Additionally, what you're asking doesn't really make a lot of sense. Search engines don't necessarily record the response headers they get from a site, because they're indexing the content. Your questions might be better on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: There are search engines that log websites response headers too. I was wondering if google did that too.